# Change complete DIV-Content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in Javascript and already know, how to change things in HTML with it.
But now, i want to change the complete div content.

I have an div with 2 buttons, one of the button is called 'Login'.
What i want is:

When the visitor clicks on 'Login', the div shows "another content", where you can login now.

How i can do it?

Edit:

DIV Content:

```
        <div id="vote" align="center">
        <span style="font-size: 30px">Voten</span><br /><br />
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
        ?>

        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function login() {
                    Change div content....
                }

                function register() {
                    alert('coming soon, lol');
                }
            </script>
            You must be logged in, to vote.<br />
            <input type="button" class="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" onclick="login()" /><br /><br />
            Not a member yet?<br />
            <input type="button" class="button" name="login" id="register" value="Register now!" onclick="register()" />
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Again: What i want is, if the visitor clicks the Login Button, the div content will change to a different html-code.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried yet.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What part are you having trouble with?  Taking an action when a button is clicked?  Making content hidden?  Making hidden content visible?

Comment: @Aarivex don't edit your post to say 'solved'. Instead choose an answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

With pure JavaScript, you have two possibilities :

1. Use the innerHTML property on the div object, that will parse you and create you DOM nodes
2. Create by yourself these DOM nodes. [Wikipedia Link for DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

**Use of [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) :**

This will use the HTML parser of the browser.

```
// You first have to select this DIV, for example by Id
var divContainer = document.getElementById('idOfDiv');

// Let's set the new HTML content of the div
divContainer.innerHTML = '<b>The HTML code you want !</b>';
```

**Creation of DOM nodes :**

```
var divContainer = document.getElementById('idOfDiv');

// You need to create the DOM nodes you want want to append
var newDomNode = document.createElement('p'); // Put as property the tag you want to create

// You have multiple choices here, you can set again the newDomNode innerHTML :
newDomNode.innerHTML = '<b>Some HTML</b>';

// Or the innerText : ( This will just put text )
newDomNode.innerText = 'Some Text to say Hello!';
```

Then you need to append the created `newDomNode` to the desired DIV, this will insert the node as the last child of the container :

```
divContainer.appendChild();
```

You can append these nodes recursively. You can for example append another DOM node to `newDomNode`.
You can also if you want use `divContainer.insertBefore()` [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) to be able to put the node where you want.

This is with pure JavaScript, it is a good way to understand how JavaScript works. Understanding the DOM is very important before going to jQuery. But in the real life it will be easier to use a library like jQuery for this.

Comment: Thanks. but no other possibilities?

Comment: My answer is more to tell you the things you need to know when you're new to JS and you want to learn it the good way before going to jQuery. But jQuery will be better to do things in a simple way.